# Buddypress: Filter Members Based on If They Have Posts

Tags: buddypress

I'm trying to filter the Buddypress Members loop to show only members that have published posts. I got the directory to display the members I wanted using the following code. However, by eliminating the standard bp_ajax_querystring( 'members' ) part after the bp_has_members, the search functionality on the page won't work. I can't seem to get the directory to display the results with both the bp_ajax_querystring( 'members' ) and the below filters. Any ideas?

```
<?php do_action( 'bp_before_members_loop' ); ?>

<?php 

    // The Query
    $user_query = new WP_User_Query( array( 'has_published_posts' => true) );

    // User Loop
    $published_users = array();

    if ( ! empty( $user_query->results ) ) {
        foreach ( $user_query->results as $user ) {
        $published_users[] = $user->ID ;

    }
    } else {
    }

    $usersimploded = implode(",",$published_users);
    ?>

    <?php if ( bp_has_members(array('include' => $usersimploded, 'type'=>'alphabetical', 'exclude' => '1,2,62'))) : ?>
```

Comment: I edited the post to show what I got to partially work. I can't figure out how to fit the original bp_ajax_querystring( 'members' ) part in, and without that, it seems the search functionality on the directory no longer works. I tried connecting both together with a "." before the array, but it just goes back to displaying all members. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Solved if anyone needs this:

```
<?php
// The Query
$user_query = new WP_User_Query( array('has_published_posts' => array('post_type'=>'post')) );

// User Loop
$published_users = array();

if ( ! empty( $user_query->results ) ) {
 foreach ( $user_query->results as $user ) {
    $published_users[] = $user->ID ;

}
} else {
}

$usersimploded = implode(",",$published_users);



if ( bp_ajax_querystring( 'members' ) =="") {
$queryString = 'type=alphabetical&action=alphabetical&include='. $usersimploded .'&page=1&exclude='.'1,2,62';
} else {
$queryString = bp_ajax_querystring( 'members' );
}
?>


<?php if ( bp_has_members( $queryString) ) : ?>
```